# How to revert the behavior of dialogs and toasts?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I have the following problem: after an crash when resuming my VM suspended with AS open, the dialogs and Toasts now occupies the whole screen.

Before, they were just a little box that appeared on bottom of screen. Now ProgressDialogs, dialogs and toasts have that all screen behavior

I'm using appcompat-21 to use the toolbar control from Android Lollipop.
What I have to look for?

Bellow the Manifest, the theme and styles files.

I've removed AS and reinstalled after passing an registry cleaner application (I'm on windows)

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2008 ZXing authors

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.

-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.google.zxing.client.android.ingresso"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="109"
    android:versionName="@string/manifest_version">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- Donut-specific flags which allow us to run on any dpi screens. -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<!--             android:screenOrientation="landscape" -->
    <application
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:name= "com.google.zxing.client.android.ingresso.App"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BarcodeActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DataMatrixActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />
        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name=".ConfigurationActivity"-->
            <!--android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"-->
            <!--android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"-->
            <!--android:screenOrientation="landscape"-->
            <!--android:stateNotNeeded="true"-->
            <!--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"-->
            <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >-->
        <!--</activity>-->
        <activity
            android:name=".ManualActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LogonActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connect" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

File res/values/styles.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ScannerTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bi_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textViewStyle"/>

    <style name="editTextStyle">
        <item name="android:color">#ff025358</item>
    </style>

    <style name="barcodeTextViewStyle">
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">-2</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="barcodeCheckBoxStyle">
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">-2</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="manualBarcodesbuttonStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">24dp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="buttonStyle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ingresso_btn</item>
    </style>

    <style name="base_activity">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:keepScreenOn">true</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/AppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bi_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="logo_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
        <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

File res/theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.ScannerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Set AppCompat’s actionBarStyle -->


    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

File res/values-21/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ScannerTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bi_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's shameful (but educational) that the following item tag:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ScannerTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bi_background</item>
</style>
```

Is the cause of all trouble, because ALL dialogs get the background because of the app's theme.

The lesson is: beware what you put in your base theme definition...